# Flutter google mobile ads only shows test ads on IOS

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, admob, google-mobile-ads

I have the following ad Repository

```
import 'package:google_mobile_ads/google_mobile_ads.dart';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:my_app/data/api/constants.dart';

class AdMobRepository {
  late String liveBannerAdId;
  late String liveInterstitualAdId;
  late String liveRewardedAdId;

  AdMobRepository() {
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      liveBannerAdId = Constants.androidBannedAdId;
      liveInterstitualAdId = Constants.androidInterstitualAdId;
      liveRewardedAdId = Constants.androidRewardedAdId;
    } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
      liveBannerAdId = Constants.iosBannerAdId;
      liveInterstitualAdId = Constants.iosInterstitualAdId;
      liveRewardedAdId = Constants.iosRewardedAdId;
    } else {
      liveBannerAdId = "";
      liveInterstitualAdId = "";
      liveRewardedAdId = "";
    }
  }

  BannerAd getBannerAd({
    required AdSize size,
    void Function(Ad, LoadAdError)? onFailedLoad,
    void Function(Ad)? onLoad,
    void Function(Ad)? onAdOpened,
    void Function(Ad)? onAdImpression,
  }) {
    return BannerAd(
      adUnitId: kReleaseMode ? liveBannerAdId : BannerAd.testAdUnitId,
      request: AdRequest(),
      size: size,
      listener: BannerAdListener(
        onAdFailedToLoad: onFailedLoad ?? onFailedLoadFallback,
        onAdLoaded: onLoad,
        onAdImpression: onAdImpression,
        onAdOpened: onAdOpened,
      ),
    );
  }

  void onFailedLoadFallback(Ad ad, LoadAdError error) {
    ad.dispose();
  }

  void getInterstitualAd({required void Function(LoadAdError) onFailedLoad, void Function(InterstitialAd)? onLoad}) {
    InterstitialAd.load(
      adUnitId: kReleaseMode ? liveInterstitualAdId : InterstitialAd.testAdUnitId,
      request: AdRequest(),
      adLoadCallback: InterstitialAdLoadCallback(
        onAdLoaded: onLoad ?? onInterstitialAdLoadedFallback,
        onAdFailedToLoad: onFailedLoad,
      ),
    );
  }

  void onInterstitialAdLoadedFallback(InterstitialAd ad) {
    ad.fullScreenContentCallback = FullScreenContentCallback(
        onAdDismissedFullScreenContent: (ad) => ad.dispose(), onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent: (ad, error) => ad.dispose());
  }

  void getRewardAd({required String userId, required void Function(LoadAdError) onFailedLoad, void Function(RewardedAd)? onLoad}) {
    RewardedAd.load(
      adUnitId: kReleaseMode ? liveRewardedAdId : RewardedAd.testAdUnitId,
      request: AdRequest(),
      rewardedAdLoadCallback: RewardedAdLoadCallback(
        onAdLoaded: onLoad ?? onRewardedAdLoadedFallback,
        onAdFailedToLoad: onFailedLoad,
      ),
      serverSideVerificationOptions: ServerSideVerificationOptions(userId: userId),
    );
  }

  void onRewardedAdLoadedFallback(RewardedAd ad) {
    ad.fullScreenContentCallback = FullScreenContentCallback(
        onAdDismissedFullScreenContent: (ad) => ad.dispose(), onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent: (ad, error) => ad.dispose());
  }
}
```

And I have the following widget for banner ads

```
class MyBannerAd extends StatefulWidget {

  const MyBannerAd();

  @override
  _MyBannerAdState createState() => _MyBannerAdState();
}

class _MyBannerAdState extends State<MyBannerAd> {
  late AdSize adSize;
  late AdMobRepository adRepository;
  late AnalyticsRepository analyticsRepository;
  bool adLoaded = false;
  BannerAd? anchoredBanner;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    adRepository = context.read<AdMobRepository>();
    analyticsRepository = context.read<AnalyticsRepository>();

    if (SizerUtil.deviceType != DeviceType.mobile && SizerUtil.orientation == Orientation.portrait) {
      adSize = AdSize.leaderboard;
    } else {
      adSize = AdSize.largeBanner;
    }

    final bannerAd = adRepository.getBannerAd(
      size: adSize,
      onFailedLoad: (ad, error) {
        print('banner ad failed to load: $error');
        ad.dispose();
      },
      onLoad: (ad) {
        setState(() {
          adLoaded = true;
          anchoredBanner = ad as BannerAd?;
        });
      },
      onAdImpression: (_) {
        analyticsRepository.sendBannerAdShownEvent();
      },
      onAdOpened: (_) {
        analyticsRepository.sendBannerAdClickEvent();
      },
    );

    bannerAd.load();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    anchoredBanner?.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<SubscriptionBloc, SubscriptionState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        final isLoaded = !adLoaded;

        if (isLoaded || state.hasSubscribed || anchoredBanner == null) return SizedBox.shrink();

        return Container(
          color: Colors.transparent,
          width: anchoredBanner!.size.width.toDouble(),
          height: anchoredBanner!.size.height.toDouble(),
          child: Center(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.white,
              child: AdWidget(
                ad: anchoredBanner!,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

But on IOS it is always showing test ads. How can this be when the app is built with flutter release mode with `flutter build ios --release`? The app is currently in review and I was thinking that these ads would stop being test ads whenever it is live on the app store.

But Apple sent us the following message

> We noticed that your app or its screenshots include test
> advertisements. Apps or metadata items that include features that are
> for test or demonstration purposes are not appropriate for the App
> Store.
>
> Next Steps
>
> To resolve this issue, please revise your app to complete, remove, or
> fully configure any partially implemented features. Please ensure your
> screenshots do not include any images of demo, test, or other
> incomplete content

So how do I get rid of the test ads? Did I miss some XCode setting or?

I am using

```
flutter: 2.5.3
google_mobile_ads: ^0.13.4
```

And I also added the GADApplicationIdentifier to my info.plist

```
<key>GADApplicationIdentifier</key>
<string>{here I have the app Id}</string>
```

And I am testing on a real device with the testflight build

**Side Note:**

In admob setting I have added the following test IDFA

00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000

which seems to work for Test ads on all IOS devices.

Comment: Did you set 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 value in AdMob Console Test devices settings?

Comment: Yes I added it under adMob > Settings > Test Devices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I needed to remove the 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 from the test settings on admob. I no longer recieve test ads after that, but I do recieve ads in the release build now.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make any code changes.

> Next Steps
>
> To resolve this issue, please revise your app to complete, remove, or
> fully configure any partially implemented features. **Please ensure
> your screenshots do not include any images of demo, test, or other
> incomplete content**

**To resolve above rejection, all you need to do is remove banner advertisement from your screenshots and submit for approval again.**